# Can we assign instance attributes in __new__?

Tags: python, python-3.9

For example if we do like:

```py
class blah(object):
    def __new__(self, **attr):
        try: self.isBlah = attr["true_or_false"]
    def __init__(self, **attr):
        if self.isBlah:
             self.blah = self.isBlah
a = blah(true_or_false=True)
print(a.blah)
```

I know that `__new__` one starts first, but can we assign value to it? Because when I do it on Python interpreter, it does not, but in website compilers, it does.

Comment: `__new__` is a *class method*; the first argument is the class not an instance, it *returns* the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The first argument passed to [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) is the class to create an instance of. So in order to do what you want the class instance must first be created — then you can add attributes to that before returning it.

Below is an example of doing that based on the code in your question. Note that when writing Python code it's usually best to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) — particularly the [Naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

```
class Class:
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        attr = kwargs.get('true_or_false', False)
        inst = super().__new__(cls)
        inst.is_blah = attr
        return inst

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if self.is_blah:
            self.blah = self.is_blah


c = Class(true_or_false=True)
print(c.blah)  # -> True
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @JuuzouSuzuya: Note that there's no advantage to doing this in the `__new__()` method, in fact it's actually slightly more work than doing it in the `__init__()` would be — which is where such thing are usually done.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for that.